# Where is App Folder in Android File Browser

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, react-native, android-emulator

I started a `virtual device` with `Android Studio`. I then executed `react-native run-android`. I want to access through the `File Browser`(Android Device Monitor) the *folder* of my app. I expect that folder to be in `system - app - MYAPP`. However, when I look there, I only see the preinstalled Apps, not the I pushed onto the `Emulator` with `react-native run-android`.

Where is the folder of my App and how would I access it?

Answer (score 0):

if you mean by the app forlder : "com.YourAppName" , you will find it in `File Browser > Android > data`